# Python: How can I divide a number completely by 2 and 3 and return -1 if not possible

Tags: python, algorithm, function, math

I want to make a function where given a number like 7 I want to factorise the number by as many 3s and 2s. If left with a remainder then return -1.

Note: Through further examples it seems any number can be made up of the addition of multiples of 3s and 2s so -1 for remainder not needed. Goal is to get as many multiples of 3 before having to add multiples of 2 to factorise completely

For example given the number 11 I want the function to return 3:3 and 2:1 as 3 fits into 11 3 times and 2 once ie. 3+2+2=7, 3+3+3+2=11, 3+3+3+2+2=13. The preference should be being able to fit as many 3s first.

This is part of a wider problem:

```
from collections import Counter
#Choose two packages of the same weight
#Choose three packages of the same weight 
#Minimum number of trips to complete all the deliveries else return -1

def getMinimumTrips(weights):
    weights_counted = Counter(weights)
    minimum_trips = 0
    print(weights_counted)
    for i in weights_counted:
        if weights_counted[i]==1:
            return -1
        elif weights_counted[i]%3==0:
            minimum_trips += (weights_counted[i]//3)
        elif weights_counted[i]%2==0:
            minimum_trips += (weights_counted[i]//2)
    return minimum_trips

print(getMinimumTrips([2, 4, 6, 6, 4, 2, 4]))
```

Possible solution:

```
#Looking at inputs that are not a multiple of 3 or 2 eg, 5, 7, 11, 13
def get_components(n):
    f3 = 0
    f2 = 0
    if n%3==1:
        f3 = (n//3)-1
        f2 = 2
    elif n%3==2:
        f3 = (n//3)
        f2=1
    return f"3:{f3}, 2:{f2}"
```

Comment: Just curious, does the output `-1` ever happen, except for input `0` or `1`?

Comment: Thinking about it I guess not, but I guess just keeping -1 if all else fails

Comment: Yes sorry, was just going to put an edit from the elif the integers that are multiples of 3 and 2 have already been filtered out so just looking at numbers such as 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 etc. And that's right looking to divide by as many 3s first so for 19 something like 3+3+3+3+3+2+2=19. I've put in a possible solution I just tried

Comment: Note, that in case of `n%3==1` we have a *special case*: we don't have a solution for `n == 1`

Comment: No worries, I've removed the case for having n=1 from being inputted into the function during the weights_counted[i]==1 condition. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are given some integer value `x` we have **3** different cases:

1. `x == 3 * n`, solution: return `3` `n` times. The easiest case.
2. `x == 3 * n + 1`, solution: return `3` `n - 1` times, then return `2` `2` times, Note that we can put `3 * n + 1 == 3 * (n - 1) + 2 + 2`
3. `x == 3 * n + 2`, solution: return `3` `n` times, then return `2`.

As one can see in cases `#1` and `#3` solutions ever exist; in case `#2` there's *no solution* for `x = 1` (we *can't return* `3` `-1` times). So far so good if `x <= 1` we return `-1` (no solutions), otherwise we perform *integer division* `//` and obtain `n`, then find *remainder* `%` and get the case (remainder `0` stands for case #1, `1` for case #2, `2` for case #3). Since the problem looks like a homework let me leave the rest (i.e. exact code) for you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method using `math.floor()`

```
import math


def get_components(n: int) -> str:
    q3 = math.floor(n / 3)
    q2 = math.floor(q3 / 2)
    if not (q3 and q2):
        return '-1'  # returning '-1' as a string here for consistency
    return f'3:{q3}, 2:{q2}'
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Passing the int 17 into the function above results in 3:5, 2:2 ie. (3*5)+(2*2)=19 when it should be (3*5)+(2*1)=17. But thanks to this I was actually able to spot an interesting pattern to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This will return 0 if you can completely factorise the number, or -1 if 1 is remaining:

```
return -(i % 3 % 2)
```

If this helps?

Comment: That was a nice way to do it, thanks although I needed to keep track of how many times 3 and 2 would go into the number i